# How to put a randomly choice option in Django?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am writing a web application in Python, using Django. I do have a drop down list of 12 items. With a current functionality, I can choose an item one by one, however, I would like to put an option which selects randomly the items in the interval of [1,12]. 
For example, by choosing the number 6 in the box, I can have 6 randomly chosen items. 
any help, hint will be appreciated a lot! thank you.

Comment: include code you'ved tried so we figure out how it should be.

Comment: Thank you @curiosity for your comment. Actually, the current code for choosing one by one from the list, was written by a former colleague. now I'm supposed to modify it to such a demand of choosing randomly. by posting a question, I just wanted to be sure if the idea would be possible or not? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Hanieh it is possible and actually, a very easy task. Django wont help you with it, you just need Python skills: read about `random.choice()`

Comment: @Pablo thank you very much. Great! Exactly, I meant that point. Since, I am new in Django, was not sure if I can handle it directly with Django, any module or just using built-in random function in Python.